# Attaching Excel Sheet to Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, attachment

I simply want to be able to attach an excel file to an outlook email using vba. It seemed simple enough but I keep getting an error.

The file is able to be attached and sent, however when the recipient opens the excel file a window pops up that says "Problem During Loading" and in he textbox below it says "Missing file:"

here's the code

```
   Sub SendReports()

Searched_Email = Array("(file destination)", "(subject of the email im searching for)", "(what i want to save the file as)", "(the email(s) its being sent to)")
Call Reports(Searched_Email)

End Sub

Function Reports(a As Variant)

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim olFldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Items
Dim olMi As MailItem
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Attachment
Dim MyPath As String

Dim subj As String
Dim saveAs As String
Dim emails As String
Dim FilePath As String


FilePath = a(0) "\"
subj = a(1)
saveAs = a(2)
emails = a(3)

MyPath = "C:\Users\temp\" & FilePath
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items
Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Set olMi = olItms.Find("[Subject] = " & Chr(34) & subj & Chr(34))
If Not (olMi Is Nothing) Then
             For Each olAtt In olMi.Attachments

                 olAtt.SaveAsFile MyPath & saveAs & ".xls"
                 Workbooks.Open (MyPath & saveAs & ".xls")

                 Call NewFormat.master 
                 ' ---- This is separate file that formats the excel file

                 ActiveWorkbook.Save
                 Set rng = Worksheets(saveAs).UsedRange
             Next olAtt
End If
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = emails
    .CC = 
    .BCC = ""
    .subject = subj
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName '--------heres where the attachment is
    .send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveWorkbook.Close
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set olAtt = Nothing
Set olMi = Nothing
Set olFldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Everything else works. From what I understand everything is correct and the file is being sent and shows up as an .xls file attachment as I wanted. However, any attempt at opening it results in the same error every time; even when I save the document and attempt to open it from my desktop.

Comment: Can you open the attachment from the Sent Items folder?

Comment: I can not. It has the same error message.

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: Just uploaded it. As I said, everything else works fine. The file gets attached and sent, but when I try to open it I get an error.

Comment: Is Excel file saved? If you replace Send with Save, does the attachment look good in the Drafts folder?

Comment: No I get the same error. The file shows the attachment as an .xls file and the name of the file is correct, however I get an error when I attempt to open it and it just appears blank.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently if I link to any file in my dropbox and attempt to attach it to an email using vba code, I will get this error.  When the file is saved to my desktop and pulled from there as an attachment, it works fine. I can only assume this is an issue with dropbox.

Comment: Dropbox? What is the full file path you pass to Attachments.Add?

Comment: it was literally this    C:\ Users\ (Me) \ Dropbox \ Reports \ report.xls      I have no clue why this gave me issues. After just saving the file to my desktop I was able to resolve the issue, but whenever my file path came from drop box, the attachment would show up in the email but wouldnt open properly.

Comment: I bet Dropbox has a component that watches that folder and sync it ot the server. Chances are the file was .locked. Do problematic messages have data in their attachments? . Look at the message in the Sent Items folder with OutlookSpy - select the message, click IMessage, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double click on the attachment, select the PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN property, click the "..." button next to the Values edit box.